# TypeScript - Click in nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to put click inside the tag?

```
this.textInputElem.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    '<div class="output" onclick="redirect()">' + this.texto + '</div>'
)
```

this redirect is not known in the component only in the index.
but I need in component

Comment: Don't program like this. Angular is not jQuery. If you would tell us what you are trying to do, perhaps we could suggest an Angular-like approach.

Comment: I need to call a function of the component in each native element inserted

Comment: I know you want to associate some click handler with the element your are inserting. Your question already says that. What I was asking is for you to take one step back and explain to us why you need to insert elements at run-time. Basically, that is a major Angular anti-pattern.

Comment: This is a chatbot, when a specific message arrives I need to make a link / button that when clicking calls a function.
This function opens a component with the message details.
It's basically this.

Comment: Put the element in your template, and control its appearance using a flag set when the message arrives. I cannot tell what you mean by "this redirect is not known in the component only in the index". Where are you trying to redirect to?

Comment: I put the function redirect () in index.html and it works, example:

<script>
      function redirect () {
         alert
     }
</ script>`

but when I put in the component it does not work, I already tried to put in the main.ts too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do not program like this. This is not how you program in Angular. In Angular, you do not insert bits of HTML into the DOM as if you were programming in jQuery ten years ago. In Angular, the DOM is defined in Angular templates. The Angular templating mechanism provides the value bindings and the event connections to the HTML in the template. The presence or absence of DOM elements--including or excluding them from the DOM--is handled by if statements and loops in the templating language.

If you stray from this orthodoxy, you will spend the rest of your life fighting against Angular. Rather than programming in Angular, you will be programming in jQuangular. You could easily find that things like Angular Universal, or even AoT, do not work as expected.

If you insert the following into the DOM

```
'<div class="output" onclick="redirect()">' + this.texto + '</div>'
```

as a string using native DOM APIs such as `insertAdjacentHtml`, Angular has no idea what you are doing. It has no idea that this is, or is not, connected or related to any specific template logic. How could it? It does not process any Angular directives or resolve any Angular property references in your big HTML string because it doesn't even know that you are doing this. It has no idea that it should try to match up `redirect()` to a method of some particular instance of some component. Therefore, as you found, this will work only if `redirect` is in the global scope.

Although I do not fully understand your use case, it seems that you should write a template looking something like:

```
<input>

<!-- Conditionally display the input text. -->
<div 
  *ngIf="displayText"
  class="output"
  (click)="redirect()"
>
  {{texto}}
</div>
```

When the message comes in, turn on the `displayText` flag:

```
displayText: boolean = false;
texto: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.chats.subscribe(text => {
    this.texto = text;
    this.displayText = true;
  });
}

redirect() {
  ...
}
```

Or something along those lines. I hope this helps.